# How to align images across different divs horizontally

Tags: html, css, image

Can you please help me understand how to align images horizontally across different divs in the same row regardless of the inner content of the div?
I've tried absolute positioning, but I'm required for this interview test to keep everything within the inner div container.

Example:
[image: here]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 product-box">
    <div class="col-md-12 background-contain">
      <p class="blue-title">Product Title 1</p>
      Staring at $500
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      <br>
      <div class="img-contain">
        <img src="materials/images/cereal_b.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="cereal" />
      </div>
      <a class="bottom-link">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 product-box">
    <div class="col-md-12 background-contain">
      <p class="blue-title">Product Title 2</p>
      Staring at 1900
      <br> Donec ornare magna sit amet erat molestie sollicitudin ac vitae lectus.</br>
      <img src="materials/images/flower_b.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="cereal" />
      <a class="bottom-link">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 product-box">
    <div class="col-md-12 background-contain">
      <p class="blue-title">Product Title 3</p>
      Staring at 1900
      <br> Cras non metus sed odio tristique imperdiet.</br>
      <img src="materials/images/machine_b.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="cereal" />
      <a class="bottom-link">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 product-box">
    <div class="col-md-12 background-contain">
      <p class="blue-title">Product Title 4</p>
      Staring at 1900
      <br> Pellentesque mattis tellus ut molestie dapibus.</br>
      <img src="materials/images/candy_b.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="cereal" />
      <a class="bottom-link">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your CSS and create a Snippet rather than linking to a screenshot.

Comment: Have you try  ` .col-md-12.background-contain img  { position : absolute ; bottom : x em; left:50%; transform : translateX(-50%); }` ?

Comment: Looks aligned to me https://jsfiddle.net/kvb5hb6f/15/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Bootstrap class -"container-fluid".
Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z5v6t048/

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 product-box">
        <div class="col-md-12 background-contain">
      <p class="blue-title">Product Title 1</p>
      Staring at $500
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      <br>
      <div class="img-contain">
        <img src="materials/images/cereal_b.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="cereal" />
      </div>
      <a class="bottom-link">Learn More</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 product-box">
       <div class="col-md-12 background-contain">
      <p class="blue-title">Product Title 2</p>
      Staring at 1900
      <br/> Donec ornare magna sit amet erat molestie sollicitudin ac vitae lectus.
      <img src="materials/images/flower_b.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="cereal" />
      <a class="bottom-link">Learn More</a>
    </div>
   </div>

</div>
```